# Laravel 5.3 can not create XSRF-TOKEN and laravel_session on Cookies

Tags: laravel, session, token

Please you can see the print screen below with problem description:
http://prntscr.com/fjk6za

Answer (score 1):

Was a problem with one of my libraries which has new line before opening php tag on this class: \n

Also this library is declared on composer:
...

`"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
      "database",
      "...",
      **"app/Libraries"**
    ],
    "files": [
      "app/Libraries/**{library_name}**.php"
    ],`

This causes redirection on login page and also blocked writing Cookies on client side: XSRF-TOKEN and laravel_sessions.

Thnx

Answer (score 0):

Straight from documentation

> After installing Laravel, you may need to configure some permissions.
>   Directories within the  storage and the bootstrap/cache directories
>   should be writable by your web server or Laravel will not run.

see more https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/installation

Comment: Was a problem with one of my libraries which has new line before opening php tag on this class: \n<?php